# Custom quantity input on add to cart help [Shopify]

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

I am having a hard time with this, hoping there is an easy answer

My products are all based on teired pricing, 1-25=$5.00, 26-50=$4.00, etc. How would I go about having the quantity entered on the product page and then passed along to the add to cart page with the correct price?

Essentially this is what I am trying to achieve (taken from the Shopify forums):

1. Create as many variants for your product as you have different unit prices. In your case, as described above, you will need 2 variants.
2. Collect quantity on the product page, and from that, determine the corresponding unit price, then update 2 fields in the Add to Cart form: variant id, and quantity. (YES, you can add x items at once on the product page).

How might I achieve this with Jquery?  I'm struggling with the Jquery code needed to collect the quantity and price and pass it to the cart.

Thanks!

Comment: I am trying to do the similar thing, can you please suggest how did you solve your problem ?

Answer (score 2):

I think writing this code without any html and post url is impossible. You must give us the link of this page. But let me try. I think you can send manually request from a jquery file to cart. Or for more security you can send a post quantity and user to another php file. On that php file you can calculate prize and post it to cart. I am not similar with shopify but I tried my luck.

```
$('#buy').click(function(){
     quan=$('#quantity').val();
     if(quantity >= 1 && quantity <=25){
            //capture the user id
            $.post("cart.php", { price: "5", quantity: quan, userId : user } );
     }else if(quantity >= 26 && quantity <=50){
            //capture the user id
            $.post("cart.php", { price: "4", quantity: quan, userId : user } );
     }
});
```

But dont forget client side scripting is dangerous. Try to use server-sided script to calculate price from quantity. Example below.

```
//Javascript

    $('#buy').click(function(){
         quan=$('#quantity').val();
         //capture the user id
         $.post("cart.php", { quantity: quan, userId = user } );
    });
```

Here is the php file to capture the variables from request and work on them.

```
 //PHP

<?php
$user= $_POST['userId'];
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
             if(quantity >= 1 && quantity <=25){
                    //Change cart. Mysql or post manually to cart php and send the price 5
             }else if(quantity >= 26 && quantity <=50){
                     //Change cart. Mysql or post manually to cart php and send the price 4
             }


?>
```